# PHP - Why single-quoted variables inside doubles are still parsed

Tags: php, string, quotes

Normally, when variables in PHP are enclosed in single quotes, they are treated as strings, i.e

```
echo '$variable';
```

will actually echo the word $variable onto the screen.

So why is it then that this string is parsed:

```
echo "'$variable'";
```

That code actually does echo the value of the variable. Why is that? It's still inside single quotes, so why does it still get parsed?

Comment: The single quotes are interpreted as part of the string, not an aspect of the code being parsed. If you want to escape and show the variable name, use `"'\$variable'"`, where you escape the `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the single quotes are inside double quotes. Anything inside double quotes gets evaluated. So, your echo statement is passed a string inside double quotes.

This string is evaluated then output. It contains single quotes and a variable.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
    $var = 10;
    echo '"$var"';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The string is wrapped in double quotes -- the single quotes are part of the *content* of the string, not part of the string's delimiter.  Therefore the single quotes have no semantic meaning whatsoever.

Your question indicates that you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of strings.  This is OK!  Strings are surprisingly complex entities, and will only get more complex if you learn lower level languages like C. I would suggest you spend some time reading up on strings both in general as well as within PHP.  A few quick google searches will honestly be better than a curated list for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's in double-quotes as well.  The outer most layer of quotes denotes what kind of string it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a double quoted string that contains two single quote characters. Once they are in the double quotes, they have no meaning to the parser.